# MongoDb or Loopback solution to get all data of collection and append a custom column with static value to each row of result

Tags: loopback

Suppose i want to take list of countries, and for some reason want to append a column `status=0` to each row.
I want to do it with loopack remote methods, or mongodb query.
I have tried `$comment` operator of mongodb in `find`, but its not working, what i want is something like bellow mysql:

```
select t.fieadA, 0 AS 'status'
from table AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loopback model, update the properties to accommodate the new property status like below

```
"status": {
  "type": "number",
  "required": true,
  "default": 0
}
```